# for loop Warning message:numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used

Tags: r, for-loop

This is the warning message i am getting for the below code. Could some help figure out what could be the problem?

"Warning message:
In 1:x : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used"

```
x1 <- c(4,17,25)

sum_function <- function(x){

  sum_fun <- 0

  for(i in 1:length(x)) {

    sum_fun <- sum_fun + i
  }

  return(sum_fun)
}

sum_function(x1)
```

Comment: The warning suggests your function looks like `for (i in 1:x)` not `1:length(x)`. Try running your code in a new session.

Comment: Do you really want to calculate `1+2+3+ ... +length(x)` by the for-loop?

Comment: If you wanted a cumulative sum of x1 you should have just written `cumsum(x1)`. The second argument to the `:`-function should not be a multi-element vector, although you code above does not actually make that mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted a `sum` of x1, you should have just written:

```
sum(x1)  # or perhaps cumsum(x1) if cumulative sums were desired.
```

The second argument to the `:`-function should not be a multi-element vector, although your code above does not actually make that mistake. You can get that same warning message with:

```
x1 <- c(4,17,25)

junk_function <- function(x){
  z <- 0
  for(i in 1:x ) {
    z <- z + i
  }
}
junk_function(x1)
```

The warning was *not* coming from the `for` function but rather from the `:`-function. The correct version depending on what you assignment or goal was:

```
x1 <- c(4,17,25)

s_function <- function(x){
  z <- 0
  for( i in x ) {
    z <- z + i
               }
return(z)}

s_function(x1)
```